# Ubuntu 16.04 : Can't seem to make numpy work in python 3.6.5 but it works fine in python 2.7.12

Tags: python, python3, pip, numpy

when I run `import numypy` in python 3 , the following appears :
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

So you might say try `pip3 install numpy`
But it is already installed which is confirmed when I run `pip3 install numpy` it shows:

`Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/shreyash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.14.3)`

I did try
 `python3 -m pip install numpy` 
but it says :
            `No module named pip`

additinal info: i use pip version 10.0.1 [check the terminal screenshot :-(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx4iy.png)

related question :
 [Can't uninstall Python 3.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035996/cant-uninstall-python-3-6])

**I'm unable to make my code run in neither of python2.7 , python3.5 , python 3.6.

numpy works fine with version 2.7 but then it encounters the same problem for using matplotlib. I'm fine with whatever python version so long as I'm able to run my code. I would prefer version 3.x though.**

Comment: Your extra 3.6 installation will have a different module folder than the built-in 3.5 version. You should be able to invoke the correct `pip` version using `PYTHON -m pip install numpy`, replacing `PYTHON` with the command for your interpreter, e.g. `python3`.

Comment: what is numpy-stl available in apt? would that fix it?

Comment: @Byte Commander  I did try that but  it says :  No module named pip

Comment: @ByteCommander My goal is to get started in ML. So I'm assuming I'll  need  pytorch(my instructor said we''ll be working  mostly with pytorch not with tensorflow),matplotlib, pandas, scipy, numpy etc. Which is why I was trying to install them. But seems that I have some problem running them. Is it okay if I uninstall python 3.6 now ? and use the default 3.5 version instead. What do you suggest? I apologise for the  digression.

Comment: You could surely remove your extra 3.6 Python installation, but make sure you do not accidentally remove the system's Python 3.5 - that would give you huge trouble.

Comment: @ByteCommander Now I'm unable to uninstall  python 3.6 . I ran sudo apt-get remove python3.6 and it says : `E: Unable to locate package python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6'`

Comment: How did you even install 3.6 in the first place? If it wasn't installed with `apt`, it can't be removed that way either.

Comment: Related question by the same asker: https://askubuntu.com/q/1035996/250300

Comment: @ByteCommander I don't remember I might have used information from various sources.