# Can't uninstall Python 3.6

Tags: python, uninstall, python3

I want to uninstall my 3.6 version without touching the original 3.5 version. So I ran

```
sudo apt-get remove python3.6
```

but the output was:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6'
```

```
$ dpkg -l python3.6
dpkg-query: no packages found matching python3.6

$ dpkg -l python3
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  python3        3.5.1-3      amd64        interactive high-level object-ori
```

```
$ apt-cache policy python3
python3:
  Installed: 3.5.1-3
  Candidate: 3.5.1-3
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.1-3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

My goal is described in [Ubuntu 16.04 : Can't seem to make numpy work in python 3.6.5 but it works fine in python 2.7.12](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035826/ubuntu-16-04-cant-seem-to-make-numpy-work-in-python-3-6-5-but-it-works-fine-i). I'm unable to make my code run in neither of python2.7, python3.5, python 3.6. I'm fine with whatever Python version so long as I'm able to run my code.

```
$ type python
python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)
$ type python3
python3 is hashed (/usr/local/bin/python3)
$ type python3.6
python3.6 is hashed (/usr/local/bin/python3.6)
```

```
$ apt list --installed 'python*'
Listing... Done
python/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed]
python-all/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-all-dev/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-apt-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.1 all [installed]
python-crypto/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.6.1-6ubuntu0.16.04.3 amd64 [installed]
python-dbus/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-dev/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-gi/xenial,now 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-ldb/xenial,now 2:1.1.24-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
python-minimal/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed]
python-numpy/xenial,now 1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python-pip/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 all [installed]
python-pip-whl/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 all [installed,automatic]
python-pkg-resources/xenial,xenial,now 20.7.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python-pyatspi/xenial,xenial,now 2.18.0+dfsg-3 all [installed,automatic]
python-samba/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.13 amd64 [installed]
python-setuptools/xenial,xenial,now 20.7.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python-talloc/xenial,now 2.1.5-2 amd64 [installed]
python-tdb/xenial,now 1.3.8-2 amd64 [installed]
python-wheel/xenial,xenial,now 0.29.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python2.7/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3 amd64 [installed]
python2.7-dev/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python2.7-minimal/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3 amd64 [installed]
python3/xenial,now 3.5.1-3 amd64 [installed]
python3-apport/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.17 all [installed]
python3-apt/xenial-updates,now 1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
python3-aptdaemon/xenial,xenial,now 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14 all [installed]
python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets/xenial,xenial,now 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14 all [installed]
python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat/xenial,xenial,now 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14 all [installed]
python3-blinker/xenial,xenial,now 1.3.dfsg2-1build1 all [installed]
python3-brlapi/xenial-updates,now 5.3.1-2ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
python3-bs4/xenial,xenial,now 4.4.1-1 all [installed]
python3-cairo/xenial,now 1.10.0+dfsg-5build1 amd64 [installed]
python3-cffi-backend/xenial,now 1.5.2-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python3-chardet/xenial,xenial,now 2.3.0-2 all [installed]
python3-checkbox-support/xenial,xenial,now 0.22-1 all [installed]
python3-commandnotfound/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.3ubuntu16.04.2 all [installed]
python3-cryptography/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.2.3-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
python3-cups/xenial,now 1.9.73-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
python3-cupshelpers/xenial,xenial,now 1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2 all [installed]
python3-dateutil/xenial,xenial,now 2.4.2-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-dbus/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 amd64 [installed]
python3-debian/xenial,xenial,now 0.1.27ubuntu2 all [installed]
python3-defer/xenial,xenial,now 1.0.6-2build1 all [installed]
python3-dev/xenial,now 3.5.1-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-distupgrade/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 1:16.04.25 all [installed]
python3-feedparser/xenial,xenial,now 5.1.3-3build1 all [installed]
python3-gdbm/xenial,now 3.5.1-1 amd64 [installed]
python3-gi/xenial,now 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python3-gi-cairo/xenial,now 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python3-guacamole/xenial,xenial,now 0.9.2-1 all [installed]
python3-html5lib/xenial,xenial,now 0.999-4 all [installed]
python3-httplib2/xenial,xenial,now 0.9.1+dfsg-1 all [installed]
python3-icu/xenial,now 1.9.2-2build1 amd64 [installed]
python3-idna/xenial,xenial,now 2.0-3 all [installed]
python3-jinja2/xenial,xenial,now 2.8-1 all [installed]
python3-jwt/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 1.3.0-1ubuntu0.1 all [installed]
python3-louis/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 2.6.4-2ubuntu0.1 all [installed]
python3-lxml/xenial,now 3.5.0-1build1 amd64 [installed]
python3-mako/xenial,xenial,now 1.0.3+ds1-1ubuntu1 all [installed]
python3-markupsafe/xenial,now 0.23-2build2 amd64 [installed]
python3-minimal/xenial,now 3.5.1-3 amd64 [installed]
python3-oauthlib/xenial,xenial,now 1.0.3-1 all [installed]
python3-padme/xenial,xenial,now 1.1.1-2 all [installed]
python3-pam/xenial,now 0.4.2-13.2ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
python3-pexpect/xenial,xenial,now 4.0.1-1 all [installed]
python3-pil/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed]
python3-pip/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 all [installed]
python3-pkg-resources/xenial,xenial,now 20.7.0-1 all [installed]
python3-plainbox/xenial,xenial,now 0.25-1 all [installed]
python3-problem-report/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.17 all [installed]
python3-ptyprocess/xenial,xenial,now 0.5-1 all [installed]
python3-pyasn1/xenial,xenial,now 0.1.9-1 all [installed]
python3-pyatspi/xenial,xenial,now 2.18.0+dfsg-3 all [installed]
python3-pycurl/xenial,now 7.43.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyparsing/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 2.0.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1 all [installed]
python3-renderpm/xenial,now 3.3.0-1 amd64 [installed]
python3-reportlab/xenial,xenial,now 3.3.0-1 all [installed]
python3-reportlab-accel/xenial,now 3.3.0-1 amd64 [installed]
python3-requests/xenial,xenial,now 2.9.1-3 all [installed]
python3-setuptools/xenial,xenial,now 20.7.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-six/xenial,xenial,now 1.10.0-3 all [installed]
python3-software-properties/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.96.20.7 all [installed]
python3-speechd/xenial,xenial,now 0.8.3-1ubuntu3 all [installed]
python3-systemd/xenial,now 231-2build1 amd64 [installed]
python3-tk/xenial,now 3.5.1-1 amd64 [installed]
python3-uno/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3 amd64 [installed]
python3-update-manager/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 1:16.04.12 all [installed]
python3-urllib3/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 1.13.1-2ubuntu0.16.04.1 all [installed]
python3-wheel/xenial,xenial,now 0.29.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-xdg/xenial,xenial,now 0.25-4 all [installed]
python3-xkit/xenial,xenial,now 0.5.0ubuntu2 all [installed]
python3-xlsxwriter/xenial,xenial,now 0.7.3-1 all [installed]
python3.5/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4 amd64 [installed]
python3.5-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3.5-minimal/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: Why do you want to uninstall python3 ? You can have both installed. Just specify the interpreter to use on the command-line aka `python2` or in the shebang with `#!/usr/bin/python2`

Comment: I am now able to  run my code using `python3.5` in the terminal  :-) Still not able to figure out how to run it using `python3`  OR  `python `though.

Comment: The answer depends upon what method you used to install Py3.6, go back through your notes (or memory). If you can link to the original instructions you followed, even better. For example, apt can remove only deb packages - it cannot see pip or flatpack or tar, etc.

Comment: @SHREYASHANARASE Thank you for the added information. It’s strange that `dpkg` show `python3` to be the version 3.6.5 while `apt` thinks it’s `python3/xenial,now 3.5.1-3 amd64`. Could you add the output of `apt-cache policy python3` to your question? BTW is your `dpkg -l` output exactly what you reported? I get another format using the same command on Ubuntu 16.04: `ii  python3             3.5.1-3        amd64          interactive high-level object-oriented lang`

Answer (score 3):

Your `python3` and `python3.6` binaries<sup>1</sup> are installed in `/usr/local/bin` which is not the default location and dpkg ([or APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get)) does not know about them. So they weren’t most likely installed by dpkg or APT. To uninstall them, just remove them from the `/usr/local/bin` folder.

#### Preliminary check

I recommend to rename them first:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.bak
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3.6.bak
```

Then check whether the version installed by APT kicks in when you run `python3`:

```sh
python3 --version # expected output: Python 3.5.2
```

If this check succeeds, you can safely remove the files `/usr/local/bin/python3.bak` and `/usr/local/bin/python3.6.bak`.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, one file might be a symlink to the other.

Comment: The output is :  `Python 3.5.2` . Can I remove these files  `/usr/local/bin/python3.bak and /usr/local/bin/python3.6.bak` now?                           I only want to uninstall python 3.6 and restore everything to normal. So that maybe at a later point I can install python 3.6  using the recommended way, which is what ?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm, in my case it also returns `Python 3.5.2`, although the package version is `3.5.1-3`. So it seems to be the 16.04 default. To get Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04, you should use PPA: https://askubuntu.com/q/865554/250300

Answer (score -2):

I suppose you could use :
`sudo -i` to get to your root

and then using:

`apt purge python3-minimal` for example.

I did this today and it worked for as far as I can tell.

Good luck

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se] and thank you for the tip! However, I am afraid your answer won’t work in this case. When OP cannot complete `apt-get remove`, then he much likely cannot complete `apt purge` which includes `apt-get remove`.