# Numpy installed only for python3.5, not for python3.6

Tags: python, python3, numpy

I have both python3.5 and python3.6 in my computer. When I try to import python in numpy3.6, I get an error. When I try to install numpy through `sudo pip3 install numpy`, I get the message `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`. How do I install numpy for python 3.6?

That's the exception I get when importing numpy:

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  6 2017, 08:44:35)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' Error in sys.excepthook: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>>>
```

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1035826/250300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure `pip` is installed with:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

and:

```
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
```

and then you can install `numpy` with:

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: I have followed your answer, but when writing "python3.6 -m pip install numpy" I get the output: Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.12.1). I added to the question the full exception I get when importing numpy in python3.6.

Comment: solved after adding --upgrade to that command. Thanks!